# CSOM Sharepoint Document library List View Properties Selected View

Tags: sharepoint, view, web-parts, csom

I am trying to automate as much as possible creation of pages, subsites, Document Libraries etc and I am facing something I am stuck for several days.

I found how to import a Document Lirary into a subsite and how to display it through
First of all I tried to get all webpart from the page a find the properties, sadly I have WebPartDefinition does not contains any Properties or... I did not look the right thing!

Anyway I tried to add a ListView of the DL with :

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="ListUrl" type="string">MyDocumentLibrary</property>
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

I added the property "ExportMode" to try to get the property to set a view.
In fact my Document library is a template and contains several views. I would like to be able to set the selected view with CSOM.
I tried to import DL, display webpart List of the DL, export the webpart, import the same XML but the selected view is incorrect.
I am probably looking for the wrong direction

Anyone faced the same?
How do you set "selected View" with CSOM?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself if it helps someone!

```
if (listOfViews.Contains(selectedView))
                {
                    View viewTarget = list.Views.GetByTitle(selectedView);
                    context.Load(viewTarget);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    Guid viewId = webPartDefinition.Id;
                    View view = list.Views.GetById(viewId);
                    ViewFieldCollection viewFieldcollection = viewTarget.ViewFields;
                    context.Load(viewFieldcollection);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    view.ViewFields.RemoveAll();
                    foreach (string viewField in viewFieldcollection)
                    {
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(viewField);
                        view.ViewFields.Add(viewField);
                    }
                    view.ViewQuery = viewTarget.ViewQuery;
                    view.RowLimit = viewTarget.RowLimit;
                    view.Update();
                    myExtranet.Context.ExecuteQuery();
                }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).